# Поиск и просмотр пользователей

Tags: php

Здесь получается только поиск, а вот когда нажимаете на пользователя, проходит по ссылке, а там ничего нет, точнее на свою страницу переходит (анкету). Как сделать, чтобы можно было просматривать на того, кого клацаете?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Counter-type" content="text/html; charset=utf=8" />
    <title>поиск</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>поиск</h2>
<form action='' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $_GET[' k
    ']; ?>' />
    <input type='submit' value='поиск'>
</form>
<hr />

<?php
include 'core/init.php';
$k     = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ";
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "first_name LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR last_name LIKE '%$each%'";
}
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("lr");

$query   = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id          = $row['user_id'];
        $title       = $row['first_name'];
        $description = $row['last_name'];
        $avatar      = $row['profile'];

        echo "<h2><a href='user?id=$id'>$title</a></h2>
        $description<br  /><img src=$avatar width=150 height = 120><br  />";

    }
} else
    echo "не найдено \"<b>$k</b>\"";
mysql_close();

?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, приводим ссылку к абсолютному виду:

```
echo "<h2><a href='/user/?id=$id'>$title</a></h2>
$description<br  /><img src=$avatar width=150 height = 120><br  />";
```

Далее в файле `/user/index.php` производим поиск пользователя с `id` полученным из `$_GET['id']` и выводим его.

Comment: так пишет Object not found! при нажатии на пользователя user это папка что ли? создал каталог user сохранил там index.php только что там нужно конкретнее написать?

Comment: всё зависит от структуры Вашего сайта, либо папка, либо ЧПУ.

Comment: пусть будет папка, там index.php что в него надо написать что бы оттуда черпалось $_GET['user_id']

Comment: согласно вашему стилю:

         $id=$_GET['id'];
         $query="select * from `users` where id=".$id;
          и так далее, думаю безопасность сами настроите, и обработку запроса и вывод тоже.

Comment: что далее это продолжение первого или уже в index.php писать, хотя бы что бы ошибки небыло Object not found!

Comment: Object not found это немножко из другой оперы. попробуйте в браузере открыть файл /user/index.php скорей всего ошибка будет где то в коде, либо если вы пользуетесь какой либо ЦМС то надо разобраться как работает ЧПУ, и каким образом будут вызываться обработчики

Comment: в коде НИЧЕГО нет, что там нужно конкретно написать хотя бы для минимума, что бы хоть пустая страница с user_id отображалась, CMS мой

Comment: ничего не надо писать, для теста я обычно использую print_r($_REQUEST); если ЦМС своя то скорей всего проблема в контроллере, как правило с подобной ошибкой любит вылетать `header` когда в ней неправильно указан адрес.